# How to write a custom query in dynamodb using php?

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

In my case I have a table name "friends" which has two attributes:

- account_id
- fb_id

I try to get all the account_id based on fb_id, and for this wrote the query as below:

```
$response = $dynamoClient->getItem ( array(
            "TableName" => "facebook_friendlist",
            "ConsistentRead" => true,
            "Key" => array(
                "fb_id" => array(
                    "S" => "171092723281123"//$fbId 
                ) 
            ),
            "ProjectionExpression" => "account_id" 
        ) );
```

But its not getting executed. I also tried to write the same query using getItem(),scan(),getIterator() but no result.

Help me out with the right way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by not getting executed? what error it is showing?

Comment: no error, i am not getting any error or any kind of response after executing this query.
I was trying other options also, one was i put account_id that is my primary key into "key" part in query then the query executed but the above query is not giving any response.

Comment: ok, I guess you are missing something, you cannot directly query/get an item if it is not a primary key(hash key), refer http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html